# Illustrator CS5: Font Transparency in Shape Layer

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using Adobe Illustrator CS5 on a Mac, and I need to make the *SK* in the circle-shape transparent. I should be able to see the background behind the logo - through the SK. I bet it's super simple, but I haven't been able to find anything on Google, since I didn't know what to search for. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change the text to outline with `Type -> Create Outlines`

Then subtract it from the circle with the Pathfinder

Comment: I knew it would be very simple. However; pointing out that text-elements needs to be outlined, would improve your answer a lot. _Type_ -> _Create Outlines_

Comment: Good Idea, I'll add it.